# How do I get a keyboard to delay about 1/2s before showing?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to turn on editing mode and show a keyboard after a new view was pushed by a navigation controller. I looked at the Docs for NSTimer and they referred me to performSelector:withObject:afterDelay. For some reason I'm getting an exception. After scanning through related threads and trying a few different things I'm no further. Here's my code and stack trace.

The idea is to call showKeyboardForNewEquipment after a 1/2s delay in the viewDidLoad. That way it'll look pretty.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you misspelled `showKeyboardForNewEquipment` (the 'd' in "keyboard" is missing) in the `@selector` directive, which is why it's an unrecognized selector at runtime. Note that the compiler can't check this.

Comment: By the way, I usually try to allow Xcode to complete method names for me or use copy/paste to avoid these kinds of spelling issues.

Comment: Wow. Nice one. Thanks for indulging me on that one. Copy and Paste and Code Completion is a good idea too.